# how to retrieve post request parameter of jquery in aspx page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i am working on a project in `c#.net` , I have a `jquery` code in my master page and the master page is included in my home page. I have created hyperlinks dynamically in my home page.
i want that when ever a user clicks on the hyperlink, instead of the wholepage only 1 part of the page with **div class=refresh1** will reload.

i have include following `jquery` in my head tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").click(function () {
            var link1 = $(".mylink").text();
            $.post("loaddata.aspx",
              {
                  link: link1
              },
              function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                  if (statusTxt == "success")
                      alert("Done!");
                  if (statusTxt == "error")
                      alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);

                  $(".refresh1").load('loaddata.aspx .part1');
              });
        });
    });

</script>
```

here mylink is class of 'a' tag.

i want that when ever the hyperlink will be clicked it will load the refresh1 class part from another page i.e from `loaddata.aspx` with `class=part1`.

in `loaddata.aspx` i want to retrive the value of link that i have passed in `post` method .how can i do it plzzzzzzzzz reply aasap.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a little confusing - you already have one use of `.load()` in your code that should load just part of the specified page. It seems to me that you could remove the `$.post()` code and just use `$(".refresh1").load('loaddata.aspx .part1', {link:link1});`. Are you asking how to implement `loaddata.aspx` so that it uses the `link` parameter from the `$.post()` request?

Comment: thnxxxx but how to retrieve value of link in my loaddata.aspx page?? u r ri8 m asking how to implement loadddata.aspx to use the link parameter

Comment: So your question could be rephrased as a single sentence: "How do I retrieve a post request parameter in an ASPX page?" If that's the problem you'll probably get more help if you add "asp" and/or "C#" tags to your question.

Comment: plzzzz hep me with the syntax to retreive the value of link is it Request.Forms["link"] ??

Comment: Well what happened when you tried that? Sorry, my C# days are far enough behind me that I can't remember off the top of my head. Maybe if you added a few more z's to "plzzzzzzzz", or put "asap" in capitals?

Comment: i tried using Request.Forms["link"] but it doesn't work. plz apply ur smartness to answer my question instead of wasting it by concentrating on 'zz' part or asap part

Comment: Hey, I'm helping, I've managed to get you to confirm what you actually need help with (which wasn't at all clear in your question), and I've added the "asp.net" and "C#" tags to your question to bring it to the attention of the people who can actually help with that. (Yes, my "plzzzz" comment was a bit sarky, but I was trying to drop the hint that that sort of thing doesn't make people want to help you.)

Comment: ok thnx no offense meant :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) like so:

```
$('a').click(function () {
  var link1 = $(this).text();
  $(".refresh1").load('loaddata.aspx .part1',{
    link : link1
  },function(data){
    //optional callback code
  });

});
```

the `.load()` fires a GET request though. To do it using POST, you must use `.post()` and parse the data it retrieves:

```
$('a').click(function () {
  var link1 = $(this).text();
  $.post('loaddata.aspx',{
    link : link1
  },function(data){
    $(data).find('.part1').appendTo('.refresh1');
  });
});
```

Comment: how to retrieve the value of link in my loaddata.aspx page??

Comment: @jonnydepp It just did. `.load()` accepts a url as the first argument, and a section of the page to retrieve as the second part, space-separated from the url.

Comment: how to access the link value in my loaddata.aspx?? by using Request.Forms["link"] or in any other way??

Comment: @jonnydepp what do you mean by "link value"?

Comment: OP doesn't know the C#.net code required to access the request parameter called "link".

Comment: link is the request parameter i am passing in post method.i want to retrieve the value of variable link in my loaddata.aspx page how to do that??

Comment: C# is beyond me. I suggest to wait for the people stalking the C# and ASP.NET tags to come answer that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Request["link"]** to get the value.
Also make sure you decode the value after you retrieve.